# Setting a checkbox as checked with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been googling and playing with every combination I know but I cannot get my checkboxes to be initialised as checked.

Example:

```
<ul class="object administrator-checkbox-list">
    <li v-for="module in modules">
        <label v-bind:for="module.id">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.modules" v-bind:value="module.id" v-bind:id="module.id">
            <span>@{{ module.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

An example of the modules data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Business",
        "checked": true
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Business 2",
        "checked": false
    },
]
```

What can I do to initially set the checked status of the checkboxes?

Comment: wich is the value of `form.modules`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To set the state of the checkbox, you need to bind the v-model to a value. The checkbox will be checked if the value is truthy. In this case, you are iterating over `modules` and each `module` has a `checked` property.

The following code will bind the checkbox to that property:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="module.checked" v-bind:id="module.id">
```

---

If you'd like to know more about how v-model works in this situation, here's a link to [the documentation about Form Input Binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html).

Comment: Also from the docs : v-bind:true-value="a" v-bind:false-value="b". In my case I used v-bind:true-value=1 v-bind:false-value=0

Comment: The answer is not really correct. `v-model` binds different attributes on different input types. `v-model` on checkboxes controls their `checked` attribute instead of `value`. See @ricardoorellana's answer for an alternate approach.

Comment: This `You shouldn't use v-model and v-bind:value on the same element` it not true for checkboxes. Im correctly using `<input type="checkbox" v-for="item in items" v-model="selectedIDs" v-bind:value="item.id">` where `selectedIDs` is array of IDs of checked checkboxes. So value MUST BE used. How would Vue know what value to add to array without `v-bind:value`?

Comment: You are right. I've edited the answer to remove the incorrect information.

Answer (score 51):

Let's say you want to pass a prop to a child component and that prop is a boolean that will determine if the checkbox is checked or not, then you have to pass the boolean value to the `v-bind:checked="booleanValue"` or the shorter way `:checked="booleanValue"`, for example:

```
<input
    id="checkbox"
    type="checkbox"
    :value="checkboxVal"
    :checked="booleanValue"
    v-on:input="checkboxVal = $event.target.value"
/>
```

That should work and the checkbox will display the checkbox with it's current boolean state (if true checked, if not unchecked).

Comment: so `v-model` actually binds to `checked`, not to `value` with `<input type=checkbox>`? What the point of also binding to value in your code example then?

Comment: The example given consider that you want to have your `checkbox` as a child component, so you cannot use `v-model` simply because you want to avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.

`v-model` creates a two-way data bindings and modifies the passed prop in the child component

Comment: Is it possible to bind `:checked` to the result of a function and passing it arguments? Something like `:checked="method(id)"`?

Comment: Yes, that's valid and possible @HMR

Answer (score 40):

In the v-model the value of the property might not be a strict boolean value and the checkbox might not 'recognise' the value as checked/unchecked. There is a neat feature in VueJS to make the conversion to true or false:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  v-model="toggle"
  true-value="yes"
  false-value="no"
>
```

Comment: Neat indeed!. Thanks!

Comment: Documentation for this in Vue 2: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1 and in Vue 3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#checkbox-2

Comment: Having tried the accepted answer, this is the only solution that worked for me. I am using vue 3.3.4

Answer (score 24):

I had similar requirements but I didn't want to use `v-model` to have the state in the parent component. Then I got this to work:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :checked="checked"
  @input="checked = $event.target.checked"
/>
```

To pass down the value from the parent, I made a small change on this and it works.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :checked="aPropFrom"
  @input="$emit('update:aPropFrom', $event.target.checked)"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue and couldn't figure out a fix for a few hours, until I realised I had incorrectly `prevented` native events from occurring with:

```
<input type="checkbox" @click.prevent="toggleConfirmedStatus(render.uuid)"
    :checked="confirmed.indexOf(render.uuid) > -1"
    :value="render.uuid"
/>
```

removing the `.prevent` from the `@click` handler fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use both hidden and checkbox type input to ensure either 0 or 1 submitted to the form. Make sure the field name are the same so only one input will be sent to the server.

```html
<input type="hidden" :name="fieldName" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" :name="fieldName" value="1" :checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an simple boolean type, so What I did is:

in my html:
  `<input type="checkbox" :checked="article.is_public" :value="article.is_public" @change="updateIsPublic($event.target.checked)">`

```
methods: {
  updateIsPublic (e) {
      this.$store.commit('articles/UPDATE_IS_PUBLIC', e);
    },
}
```

Store

```
 UPDATE_IS_PUBLIC(state, value) {
    state.article.is_public = value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap vue
if value is a "1" then value="1" and for "0" unchecked-value="0"

Comment: <b-form-checkbox size="sm" v-model="row.item.active" value="1" unchecked-value="0"  name="check-button" switch></b-form-checkbox>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```html
<input v-if = "module.checked == true" checked type="checkbox" >
<input v-else-if = "module.checked == false"  type="checkbox" >
```

I have solved this with use of v-if and v-else-if

Comment: This will cause a variety of problems when it comes to form validation, accessibility and such. Not recommended at all. Please look at other answers.