# VueJS: how to set default state to checkbox

Tags: vue.js

Staring blind at something supposingly very simple. I have a Vue application which contains a checkbox. Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <label>Completed</label>
  <input
     type="checkbox"
     class="form-control"
     id="checkbox"
     v-model="todo.checked"
  >
  {{todo.checked}}
</div>


<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Add",
  data() {
    return {
      todo: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo(e) {
      const path = "http://localhost:5000/api/todos";

      let newTodo = {
        name: this.todo.name,
        description: this.todo.description,
        completed: this.todo.checked
      };
      console.log("Todo: ", newTodo.completed);
      axios
        .post(path, newTodo)
        .then(res => {
          console.error("Todo item added successfully");
          this.$router.push({ path: "/todos", query: { alert: "Todo added" } });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is a todo app where the user submits a form to add a todo item via a REST API.

The problem is that the first time a user submits the form (and does not touch the checkbox) I'm getting an empty 'completed'. When a user submits the form with clicking the checkbox (either to an true or false state) it works. So the problem is happens only first time when the checkbox is not clicked.

I would want to change my code so that the value of the checkbox is always by default set to 'false', unless the user toggles it.

How can this be done with VueJS

Comment: How do you currently initialise `todo`?

Comment: `value` of a checkbox never changes. Only `checked` state.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have updated the original post to paste my JS functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: i think this question has been answered in a similar post..
[Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001483/10692539)

Comment: The `todo.checked` property (among others) does not initially exist. This is an immediate red flag in Vue code. See [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: @claeusdev I came across that post but I don't know what this v-bind:id="module.id" does

Comment: @connexo Sorry man, I just don't get what you are saying. Every tutorial on the internet says to use v-model.

Comment: @connexo Read up on checkboxes here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox Generally, `v-model` is syntactic sugar for `:value=..` and `v-on:input=..`, which is a **Vue property and a Vue event**, not DOM properties/events. Vue out-of-the-box translates the model to which checkboxes are checked and which are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you create your `todo` item in your data attribute, you should set the default value of that todo item there.

```
  data() {
    return {
      todo: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        checked: false
      }
    };
  },
```

This ensures both that you have a default value for your eventual call to your api, as well as proper reactivity when recalculating computed properties and such.

An alternative would be to set a default value when sending your request to the api, but this will leave you with problems where changes to `todo` are not registered properly, and result in weird bugs where you think a computer property would change, but in fact does not change.

```
  let newTodo = {
    name: this.todo.name || '',
    description: this.todo.description || '',
    completed: this.todo.checked || false
  };
```