# How can I fill checkboxes with data I got from relation

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm using many to many relations between my *students* and *lessons* table. Multiple students can have multiple lessons. Relations works very good. I can create new record with selecting lessons with checkboxes and they go into relation.

But when I need to edit them, the value of checkboxes should be activated.

For example, if existing student has English and Maths lessons the checkboxes should be activated on edit page of that student. Other checkboxes should be disabled.

I can display the lessons from pivot table on detail page with no problem. But this issue blocks me. I can't find out how can I fix it.

I get the data from controller using `Student::with` and pass it as a prop, then I get that in my Vue component.

**That is how I pass relation and data to edit page**

```
public function edit(Student $student)
    {
        $lessons = $student->lessons()->get();

        return view('edit')->with(['student' => $student, 'lessons' =>  $lessons]);
    }
```

**How I get the props:**

```
<student-edit-component :student="{{$student}}" :lessons="{{$lessons}}">

</student-edit-component>
```

I declare the props like this in Vue component: `props: ['student','lessons']`

**One checkbox that I use (every checkbox is the same, (except value)**

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-3">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4" v-model="selectedLessons">
    <label class="form-check-label">History</label>
</div>
```

**Shortly,**  there are 4 checkboxes on my edit page. If the existing student is getting Maths and English lessons these should be activated when user goes into the edit page.

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `get()` method use `pluck()`;

```
$lessons = $student->lessons()->pluck('lession_id')->toArray();
```

It will return you an array, now you can check that value is exist in this array, if yes, you can mark checkbox as checked

Comment: I get the ID of them like this thank you. Please, can you show how can I handle them on Vue side?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of Vue end but https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001483/9978078 this answer can help you :)